# What is the best way to display a destructive action on this component?

Tags: usability, mobile, material-design

The final assignment from my course is to create a mobile application similar to [AnkiDroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ichi2.anki&hl=en) where the user can create flashcards to study.

I'm not sure about how to display a destructive action on the flashcard component.

Is there a better way to show that?
I currently enabled a swipe left action. I don't know if is that ok, though.

[image]

Swipe action
[image]

Comment: What is the exact action that you are trying to implement? Removing questions?

Comment: I want to display an icon to remove the cards.

Answer (score 1):

People won't find the delete button, as gpgpgp says, you will find out in the do a usability test.

Since (I assume) you can have a lot of flashcards, the best way to delete them would be using checkboxes outside the flashcard.

In the list you have the checkboxes at the left, so you can select one or multiple ones and delete them form the menu, like Gmail.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

That swipe left action to get the delete button is more common in chat UI. Not sure many users would know to swipe left in this non-chat UI. But that would come out of usability testing. You could keep this interaction, as well as add another interaction so you have a "backup". This alternate interaction could be a simple X icon to delete, top right corner of card.